# Meteor + CFS + DigitalOcean bug

Tags: meteor, nginx, collectionfs

I am not sure what happened because everything was working fine but now there is a weird bug on my app.

I had an app hosted on Modulus at www.raiseyourflag.com
I then created a version of it in React and Moved it to DigitalOcean at react.raiseyourflag.com to test and everything was working fine (all I did was import the Modulus DB into Compose.io)

Then I changed the nginx config to point to www.raiseyourflag.com and changed the DNS for www to point to the DO droplet and now all the images are getting a 404 but when I do something like `CareerImages.findOne();` I get an Object and if I do `CareerImages.findOne().url({stores: 'careerLargeImages'})` I get the url but when I go to it, I get a 404.

Is there any additional setup I should be performing on nginx to set so that `/cfs` files work.

I am using S3.

Also, now on localhost i get `http://localhost:3000/cfs/files/careerImages/MoaFx95kSuZ3yTDvX/choreographer.jpg?store=largeCareerImages net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH` which wasn't happening before either :/